# Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna make a logout feature for my app, here's my SettingsActivity:

```
class SettingsActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySettingsBinding
    private lateinit var mUserDetails: User
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        supportActionBar?.hide()
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        }
        else {
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }

        binding.toolbarUserProfileActivity.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24)
        binding.toolbarUserProfileActivity.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@SettingsActivity, DashboardActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        disableEditProfile()

        binding.btnLogout.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.tvEdit.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    private fun getUserDetails(){
        showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
        FireStoreClass().getUsersDetails(this)
    }

    fun loadUserDetailsSuccess(user: User){
        mUserDetails = user
        hideProgresDialog()

        GlideLoader(this@SettingsActivity).loadUserPicture(user.image, binding.tvUserImageSetting)
        binding.etFirstNameSetting.setText(user.firstName)
        binding.etLastNameSetting.setText(user.lastName)
        binding.etEmailSetting.setText(user.email)
        if (mUserDetails.mobile != 0L){
            binding.etMobileNumberSetting.setText(mUserDetails.mobile.toString())
        }
        binding.etAddressSetting.setText(user.address)
        binding.etPosCodeSetting.setText(mUserDetails.codepos.toString())
        if (user.gender == Constants.MALE){
            binding.btnGenderMale.isChecked
        }else{
            binding.btnGenderFemale.isChecked
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        getUserDetails()
    }

    private fun disableEditProfile(){
        binding.tvUserImageSetting.isEnabled = false
        binding.etFirstNameSetting.isEnabled = false
        binding.etLastNameSetting.isEnabled = false
        binding.etEmailSetting.isEnabled = false
        binding.etMobileNumberSetting.isEnabled = false
        binding.etAddressSetting.isEnabled = false
        binding.etPosCodeSetting.isEnabled = false
        binding.rgGender.isEnabled = false
    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        if (v != null){
            when(v.id){
                R.id.tv_edit -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this@SettingsActivity, UserProfileActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS, mUserDetails)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                R.id.btn_logout -> {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
                    Intent(this@SettingsActivity, LoginActivity::class.java).also {
                        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    fun sellerLoggedInSuccess(seller: Seller){
        //hide progress bar
        hideProgresDialog()

        //userType 0 = admin...... userType 1 = user..... userType 2 = seller
        if (seller.userType == 2){
            if (seller.profileComplete == 0){
                //jika profile user belum complete arahkan user ke activity SellerProfileActivity
                val intent = Intent(this@SettingsActivity, SellerProfileActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SELLER_DETAILS, seller)
                startActivity(intent)
            }else{
                //jika profile seller sudah complete langsung arahkan ke SellerActivity
                val intent = Intent(this@SettingsActivity, SellerActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SELLER_DETAILS, seller)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }else{
            hideProgresDialog()
            showErrorSnackBar(R.string.msg_login_seller_unsuccess.toString(), true)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

this is my setting_activity layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.user.SettingsActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_image_height"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_header_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/auth_screens_background"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_user_profile_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_tittle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="-25dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:text="@string/tittle_setting"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fl_header_bg">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fl_user_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_user_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_user_image_size"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_user_image_marginTop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_user_image_setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/profile_user_photo_margin"
                    android:background="@color/colorLightGrey"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_placeholder"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/user_image_background"/>
            </FrameLayout>


            <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_edit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lbl_edit"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/setting_edit_label_textSize"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/setting_edit_label_marginStartEnd"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/setting_edit_label_marginTopBottom"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/setting_edit_label_marginStartEnd"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/setting_edit_label_marginTopBottom"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fl_user_image"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/til_first_name"/>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_first_name"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_edit">

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_first_name_setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_last_name"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_last_name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_first_name">

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_last_name_setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_email_reg"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/er_hint_email_id"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_last_name">

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email_setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_password_reg"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/et_hint_mobile_number"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_email_reg">

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_mobile_number_setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_address"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/et_hint_address"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_password_reg">

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_address_setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_pos_code"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/et_hint_codepos"
                android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_address">

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_pos_code_setting"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:padding="@dimen/et_padding"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/et_textSize"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_gender"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_radio_button_height"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_logout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_pos_code">

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_gender_male"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/profile_radio_button_marginStartEnd"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/drawable_gender_selector_tab"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/gender_lbl_male"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/drawable_gender_tab_text_color"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPRadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_gender_female"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/profile_radio_button_marginStartEnd"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/drawable_gender_selector_tab"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/gender_lbl_female"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/drawable_gender_tab_text_color"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </RadioGroup>


            <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_padding"
                android:text="@string/lbl_btn_logout"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/btn_textSize"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rg_gender"/>



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my fireStoreClass :

```
class FireStoreClass {
private val mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

fun registerUser(activity: RegisterActivity, userInfo: User){

    mFirestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(userInfo.id)
        .set(userInfo, SetOptions.merge())
        .addOnSuccessListener{
            activity.userRegistrationSuccess()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {e ->
            activity.hideProgresDialog()
            Log.e(
                activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Error While Registering User.",
                e
            )
        }
}

fun getCurrentUserID(): String{
    //Instance dari currentUser menggunakan FirebaseAuth
    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    //variabel yang digunakan untuk menetapkan currentUserID
    var currentUserID = ""
    if (currentUser != null){
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }
    return currentUserID
}


@SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
fun getUsersDetails(activity: Activity){
    mFirestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(getCurrentUserID())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {document ->
            Log.i(activity.javaClass.simpleName, document.toString())

            //menerima document snapshot yang akan dikonversi ke User Data model object.
            val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!
            val username = " " + user.firstName + " " + user.lastName

            val sharedPreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.PLAGRO_PREFERENCES,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE
            )

            val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor= sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putString(
                //key = logged_in_username
                //value = firstname dan lastname
                Constants.LOGGED_IN_USERNAME,
                username
            )
            editor.apply()


            //START
            when(activity){
                is LoginActivity -> {
                    activity.userLoggedInSuccess(user)
                }
                is SettingsActivity -> {
                    activity.loadUserDetailsSuccess(user)
                }
            }
            //END
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
        when(activity){
            is LoginActivity ->{
                activity.hideProgresDialog()
            }
            is SettingsActivity -> {
                activity.hideProgresDialog()
            }
        }
            Log.e(
                activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                e.toString()
            )
        }
}

fun updateUserProfileData(activity: Activity, userHashMap: HashMap<String, Any>){
    mFirestore.collection(Constants.USERS).document(getCurrentUserID())
        .update(userHashMap)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            when (activity) {
                is UserProfileActivity -> {
                    activity.userProfileUpdateSuccess()
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            when (activity) {
                is UserProfileActivity -> {
                activity.hideProgresDialog()
            }
        }
            Log.e(
                activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                "Error while updating the user details",
                e
            )
        }
}

fun uploadImageToCloudStorage(activity: Activity, ImageFileURI: Uri?){
    val storageRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child(
        Constants.USER_PROFILE_IMAGE + System.currentTimeMillis() + "."
    + Constants.getFileExtension(
            activity, ImageFileURI
       )
    )

    storageRef.putFile(ImageFileURI!!).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
        Log.e(
            "firebase Image URL",
            taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl.toString()
        )

        taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
            .addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                Log.e("Downloadable Image URL", uri.toString())
                when(activity){
                    is UserProfileActivity ->{
                        activity.imageUploadSuccess(uri.toString())
                    }
                }
            }

    }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            when(activity){
                is UserProfileActivity ->{
                    activity.hideProgresDialog()
                }
            }
            Log.e(
                activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                exception.message,
                exception
            )
        }
}
```

}

when i run the app and try to logout an user i got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4341)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4373)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.forPath(DocumentReference.java:81)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(CollectionReference.java:104)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.firestore.FireStoreClass.getUsersDetails(fireStoreClass.kt:136)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activity.user.SettingsActivity.getUserDetails(SettingsActivity.kt:55)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activity.user.SettingsActivity.onResume(SettingsActivity.kt:80)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4331)
```

does anyone have solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to come from this code inside `getUsersDetails`:

```
mFirestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
    .document(getCurrentUserID())
```

So my guess is that `getCurrentUserID()` returns `null` or an empty string.

Given this implementation:

```
fun getCurrentUserID(): String{
    //Instance dari currentUser menggunakan FirebaseAuth
    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    //variabel yang digunakan untuk menetapkan currentUserID
    var currentUserID = ""
    if (currentUser != null){
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }
    return currentUserID
}
```

The `getCurrentUserID` returns an empty string when `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser` is null. You'll want to deal with this in your `getUsersDetails` function by checking for `null`/empty

```
fun getUsersDetails(activity: Activity){
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getCurrentUserID()) { // 
    mFirestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(getCurrentUserID())
        ...
```